# Online judge keeps telling i have wrong answer

Tags: c

##### This is the problem:

Lili is organizing a competition at her school. There are N × N people in a room-sized N × N and each one of them belongs to a team. The team is numbered between 1 to N. In the room, people wear a shirt with numbers between 0 to N indicating team number they come from. People that wears number 0 is spectator.

Lili wants to know whether each team consists of at least N members and are in the room. Help Lili to count how many incomplete teams in the room.

Input:
Input consists of one integer N , number of team participating in this competition followed by N lines consisting of N integers Aij with value between 0 and N inclusive, each representing the numbers in the people’s shirts.

##### Constraints:

1 ≤ N ≤ 100

##### Output:

Output the number of incomplete teams in the room.

##### Sample input 1:

```
2
1 0
2 2
```

##### Output 1:

```
1
```

##### Sample input 2:

```
3
3 0 2
2 0 2
1 3 3
```

##### Output 2:

```
1
```

##### This is my current code but it keeps saying wrong answer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int n, array[101][101], i, j, count = 0, k, x = 0;

  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
    }
  }

  for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (array[i][j] == k + 1) {
          count += 1;
        }
      }
    }

    if (count != n) {
      x += 1;
    }
    count = 0;
  }

  printf("%d\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to ask the online judge site.  How can we possibly know what tricky case it's using to trip up your program?

Comment: array[101][101], maybe they are testing with a thousand teams? also count != n should maybe be count < n

Comment: Also, your check is _O(N³)_, so it is possible your algorithm takes too long time.

Comment: Like what was mentioned above, you should be creating your array after you know the value of `n` (N) so that you can make your array length [n][n]. Your code might be right and it is crashing when they input a very large room

Comment: Agreed with @Sven: `if (count != n)` should be `if (count < n)` because the problem states *each team consists of **at least** N members*.

Comment: Let me add that it is somewhat counter-productive to help, these online tests are supposed to check programming skills, and in this case they are unfortunately not good enough as there are multiple mistakes and the algorithm is inefficient. Welcome to SO though, and good luck with your programming career...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you do not need a 2D array of size NxN, but a single 1D array of size N (or just N-1) to count how many people are in each team.

And as you need a dynamic size array (N is only known at run time), you can simply use an allocated array of integers. Because I would bet a coin that you problem comes when N > 101...

Algo in pseudo-code:

```
read N
alloc an array teams of size N-1 and initialize it with 0
loop N * N times
| read a shirt number i
| if i > 0
| | increase teams[i - 1]
let incomplete be a 0 value integer
loop N-1 times
| if teams[i] < N
| | increase incomplete
output incomplete
```

Comment: But they *don't* need a dynamic sized array.  They have a modest upper bound on the size of the array they need, so they can do as they set out to do, and simply declare an ordinary array large enough to handle the largest problem.  I would absolutely recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance your solution seems correct excepting for two flaws:

1. `count != n` expression should be `count < n`
2. It might be too slow. @Serge Ballesta solution is `O(N^2)` but yours is `O(N^3)`

a 101x101 array is big enough, you could even use a 100x100 array instead. You can also allocate a NxN array using malloc, which would make your code more flexible but also a bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Although StackOverflow is not the right site for this question, here we go. The mistake lies here:

```c
if (count != n) {
    x += 1;
}
```

The problem statement mentioned that the size of the incomplete team is **less** than N. Change the sign `!=` to `<`, and the algorithm is correct. But, It may not be accepted by the online judge since it can be optimized further. Here's the optimized version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    /**
     * arr[i] stores the size of (i + 1)th team.
     * it's not necessary to store the spectator's count.
     */
    int arr[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        arr[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            int team;
            scanf("%d", &team);
            if (team > 0) {
                /* incrementing the size of team */
                arr[team - 1]++;
            }
        }
    }
    int incomplete_teams = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < N) {
            incomplete_teams++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", incomplete_teams);
    return 0;
}
```